# FlyingSaucerPDF repeat a rowspan table cell on each new page

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing, html-table

I am using FlyingSaucerPDF to print a HTML table where cells in first column can span a large number of rows possibly broken by a page. When it IS broken by a page I want to repeat that row spanning cell on the next page, so the reader has that detail on any page it's relevant just like a prepeating THEAD.

Heres an example of the layout I'm using

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

      .header {
        position: running(header);
      }

      .footer {
        display: block; text-align: center;
        position: running(footer);
      }

      .content {
        page-break-after: always;
      }

      @page {
        @top-center { content: element(header); }
      }
      @page {
        @bottom-center { content: element(footer) }
      }

      table { -fs-table-paginate: paginate; }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='header'>Header</div>
    <div class='footer'>Footer</div>
    <div class='content'>
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr><th colspan="2">spanning cols</th></tr>
          <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="60" style="-fs-table-cell-rowspan:60">spanning rows</td>
            <td>B</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
          <tr><td>B</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```